Unable to Boot when restore OS from Linode to Digital Ocean
I have done a process in creating images using fsarchiver.
Here is the point :

Doing the OS backup in Linode
Restore in new VPS instance of Linode working without any issue
Restore in Digital Ocean unfortunately not working

Here is what I have configured.
Doing this command :
mount /dev/vda1 /mnt
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/vda
update-grub

Note that the device map between linode (dev/sda) and DO is different (/dev/vda1) so I should mount it differently.
I also checked the /etc/network/interface in DO VPS and all is configured automatically by DO system, so nothing need to be configured.
Modify the /etc/fstab
UUID=f0211307-e4dd-9b78-390f-119f0d68b513      /       ext4    relatime,quota,grpquota,usrquota,rw,errors=remount-ro   0       1
UUID=f1408ea6-59a0-11ed-bc9d-525400000001  none  swap  sw                0  0
UUID=C294-8524  /boot/efi  vfat  umask=0077  0  1

I got the UUID as I have ran blkid
Do you have any suggestion how to make this work?
Thank you for any of your ideas.
